# Problems with comparing characters of integer casted as a String

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I'm not sure where I'm wrong, could someone please help me out.

Given a 3-digit positive integer, return true if exactly 2 digits are the same.

match2(414) → true
match2(555) → false
match2(120) → false

```
boolean match2(int num) {
  String numBer = num +"";
  char first, second, third;
  first = numBer.charAt(0);
  second = numBer.charAt(1);
  third = numBer.charAt(2);

  if (first == second && second != third) {
  return true;
  }

  else if (second == third && first != second) {
  return true;
  }

  else if (first == third && second != third){
  return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: do not use "==" when comparing strings, its better to use equals() method.

Comment: Thanks I have figured it out

Comment: @GregorioMerazJr. the OP is only using `==` on chars as far as I can tell, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: lol, sorry, cant see the code since im at work, so i just guessed by the title of the question.

Comment: This code edit is now correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (first == second || first == third)
  return true;
```

The condition is true, so `true` is *immediately* returned at this point without waiting to see if some later `if` condition returns `false`.  You will need to put your checks in a different order instead.

Comment: This will also return true if all 3 digits are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If Java 8 is an option you can consider the following solution

```
public static boolean checkIntChars(int number){
    String str = String.valueOf(number);
    Map<String, Long> frequentChars = Arrays.stream(str.split("")).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting()));
    return frequentChars.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue()==2).findAny().isPresent();
}
```